# C++ how to pass a boost shared pointer of this instance of class to nested class object?

Tags: c++, class, boost, shared-ptr

So we have (pseudo code):

```
class A
{
 A(shared_ptr parent){}
}

class B
{
 A *a;
 B()
 {
  a = new A(boost::shared_ptr(this));
 }
}
```

Is it possible to do such thing with shared_ptr in C++ and how to do it in real C++ code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `enable_shared_from_this`:

```
#include <memory>

class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<B>
{
  A * a;
public:
  B() : a(new A(std::shared_from_this())) { }
};
```

(This is for C++0x; Boost should work similarly.)

Just making a shared pointer from `this` is tricky because you might shoot your own foot off. Inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this` makes this easier.

Word of warning: Your construction with the naked `A` pointer seems to defeat the purpose of using resource-managing classes. Why not make `a` into a smart pointer, too? Maybe a `unique_ptr`?